# Android Device manager

Tags: android-device-manager

I just recently know about Android Device Manager. So i tested it on my own phone (moto g2). Then i thought, lets have some fun. So, i ask for gmail account and password from my friend. After getting that, i went to google in her account and then to Android Device Manager. But her phone (Mi4i) had just two option into it "ring  | enable lock and erase". So i just click on option "enable lock and erase" hoping that before doing anything it will ask yes or no. But instead it said done or something. Just tell how can i undo it and what exactly happened when i clicked that button?? i would really appreciate.

Comment: It will erase everything (Internal Storage) on her phone as soon as the device will connect to Google servers? Time to apologize to your friend! Just so you know: "enable lock and erase" -- I think it's plain English, and nothing much is needed. Anyhow, "have some fun". :)

Comment: If you are still wondering what did it do, check out [this answer by Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160500?hl=en).